# How to identify what projects have been affected by a code change

Tags: delphi, svn, dependency-management, delphi-5

I have a large application to manage consisting of of three or four executables and as many as fifty .dlls.  Many of the source code files are shared across many of the projects.

The problem is a familiar one to many of us - if I change some source code I want to be able to identify which of the binaries will change and, therefore, what it is appropriate to retest.

A simple approach would be simply to compare file sizes.  That is an 80% acceptable solution, but there is at least a theoretical possibility of missing something.  Secondly, it gives me very little indication as to WHAT has changed;  It would be ideal to get some form of report on this so I can then filter out irrelevant (e.g. dates/versions copyrights etc..)

On the plus side :

1. all my .dcus are in a row - I mean they are all built into a single folder
2. the build is controlled by a script (.bat)(easy, for example, to emit .obj files if that helps)
3. svn makes it easy to collect together any (two) revisions for comparison

On the minus side

1. There is no policy to include all used units in all projects; some units get included because they are on a search path.
2. Just knowing that a changed unit is used/compiled by a project is not sufficient proof that the binary is affected.

Before I begin writing some code to solve the problem I would like to ask the panel what suggestions they might have as to how to approach this.

The rules of StackOverflow forbid me to ask for recommended software, but if anyone has any positive experiences of continuous integration tools that would help - great

I am open to any suggestion or observation that is relevant in this context.

Comment: Retest everything seems like the obvious approach. If you try to get cute, you'll get it wrong. What's the downside of doing that?

Comment: That would be my ultimate goal but I need an interim solution for political reasons.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - how might I get it wrong? (aka 'How hard can it be?' :) )

Comment: The way you get it wrong is that you don't correctly identify the components that need to be retested. Why don't you just retest everything? You've got that automated right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sorry, no.  My customer has yet to be convinced of the benefits of automated testing due to 'bad experiences' with it in the past.  I have advised them that is the way forward but it may never happen.  Being able to show/identify how code changes affect other projects is part of the gentle persuasion process.

Comment: Hard to imagine what those "bad experiences" could be. Anyway, that's your problem I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your question boils down to knowing which units are contained in your various executables. Since you are using search paths, it will be hard for you to work this out ahead of time. The most robust way to find out is to consult the .map file that the compiler emits. This contains a list of all units contained in your executable.

Once you know which units are contained in each executable, you need to know whether or not anything has changed in those units. That information is contained in your revision control system. Put this all together and you have the information that you need.

Of course, just because the source code for a unit has changed, you might argue that re-testing is not needed. Perhaps the only change made was the version, or the date in a copyright label or some such. But it is asking too much to be able to ask a computer to make such a judgement. At some point you need a human to step up and take responsibility.

What is odd about this though is that you are asking the question at all. It seems to me to be enormously risky to attempt partial testing. I cannot understand why you don't simply retest the entire product.

Comment: You are preaching to the converted; If I had my way I would rebuild, retest and re-release the entire suite as part of the build process.  FYI - the 50 or so .dlls are apps in their own right (with a launcher app) so your point has more valididty than perhaps you realised when you made it.  It is a case of 'the art of the possible' at this stage, though.

Comment: I am going with 'Map Files' as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After using it for > 10 years for commercial in-house and freelancer work in large projects, I can recommend to try [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). It is a build tool which supports dependencies, and has many very helpful features.

Apache Ant also integrates nicely with CI tools such as Hudson/Jenkins, Bamboo etc.

Another suggestion - based on experience with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) - is to design the general software architecture as modular as possible. If modules (single or multiple source or DCU files in one directory) use a version number in the directory name as a version number, it is possible to control exactly how application are composed from these modules.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with ant.  Is it not fair to say that I would need to define the dependencies in an ant script?  I think what I am looking for is a method to discover dependencies.

Comment: @HughJones my suggestion is to define the dependencies once and then manage them using scripts, where you can see when and where a dependency had to be changed. I do not know a Delphi tool which could infer dependencies automatically.

Comment: my problem is that dependencies change  when programmers edit units.

Comment: @HughJones if programmers edit units in a way that the project requires a newer version of a dependency, or a new dependecy is introduced, they must also add the path to the new/changed dependency, and update the build script accordingly. Otherwise the project will not compile. If the programmers edit it in a way which still can be compiled with the current version(s) of the dependencies, this is not a true dependency change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to program such a tool yourself the approach would be something like this:

1. First you need to detect wheter there were any changes made to seperate source files. As you already figured out comparing the file size is bad idea as the file size can stay the same despite lots of changes made to it (as long as there is same amount of text in pas file its size won't change). So instead you could check the last modification time for specific file or create some hash value like MD5 hash for comparison (can be quite slow).
2. Then you need to generate yourself a dependancy tree which will tell you which files are used for which project/subproject.
3. Finally based on changes detected in seperate files you check the dependancy tree to see which projects needs to be recompiled.

The problem of such approach is that you would probably have to update the dependancy tree manually each time when new unit is added to the project or an existing one is removed from the project.

But the best way would be to go and use some version controll software istead of reinventing the wheel. I myself like the way how GIT works and I belive that with proper implementation of GIT into the project mannager itself could be quite powerfull do to GIT support of branching/subbranching (each project is its own branch, each version of your software can be its own subbranch).

Now latest version of Delphi does have GIT integration done though SVN but this unfortunately limits some of best GIT functionality. So if you maybe decide to go and integrate GIT support directly into Delphi I'm first in line to use it.

Comment: Asker is using Delphi 5 so vcs integration is rather moot. Integration isn't really the issue though. I don't use integration with the IDE but I sure as heck use vcs. And suggesting specific vcs systems is again beside the point. Switching to git is hardly the solution. In any case, asker already has a vcs solution in place. Checking hashes won't give much useful info though. It's easy enough to have no mods to a file, but different hashes. Also, two different files may have the same hash.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - my thoughts exactly.  It is a simple enough matter to 'walk' the dependency tree and find out which units have changed between revisions, but the really thorny problem is establishing what gets linked in.  .dcu .obj and .map files are all candidates for analysis.  What else might I consider ?

Comment: @HughJones I've already written an answer. The .map file has the information you need.